# How to scrape tables data from chartink website to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I want to scrape table data from this link https://chartink.com/screener/copy-orb-5min-6 and show the table data to my google sheets. Look at the img I attached

I'm using =importxml("https://chartink.com/screener/copy-orb-5min-6", "table", 1) but not getting the data [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbLsQ.png)

Comment: syntax-wise that formula you used should be `=importhtml("https://chartink.com/screener/copy-orb-5min-6", "table", 1)` or `=importxml("https://chartink.com/screener/copy-orb-5min-6", "//body")` but in this case table is not accessible with any import fx (importxml, importhtml, importdata)

Answer (score 0):

Chartink results are populated when a post request is sent to chartink. The table won't be available if you try to directly read the HTML. Out of the things I tried, only rendering the page through selenium and using requests to send a post request to the page works.